# How to get product year of Android device, is it possible?

Tags: android, android-build

I want to get more information about the android devices which are using my application.
I have that two info;

```
String deviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String osVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Additionally, i want to get product year of devices. I read and search about that but i think it is not possible to get product year of phone programmatically.

If it is not possible, are there any databases or documents which have a table of android device name and product years?

Comment: I don't think so we not getting product year.As per this source :https://gist.github.com/VenomVendor/5415900

Comment: Have a look at this, might be useful:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#TIME

Comment: i see from there, it is not possible to get product year. Have you two guys got any suggestion about that requirement? Any databases or any list of devices with product years?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get product year of device programmatically. But [this site](http://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3) has good and large database of phones with all OS. I took all this devices to my own database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook's Device Year Class library:
https://github.com/facebook/device-year-class